# detect whether it's the the last element using is()

Tags: jquery

I tried to count the length number and it work, but that method is too much of code.. I tried is() :

```
$(document).on('click', 'li', function () {

    $(this).remove();
    if ($(this).is(':last')) {
        alert('last');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TgfeT/
It did not work..

Comment: alert before you delete element ?

Comment: It works if you don't remove it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're removing it, then asking it if it's the last after it no longer exists in the DOM. That can't work. The last *what*? It's just a decoupled DOM element at that point.

You need to reverse the order, and ask if it's the `:last` *before* you take it out of its context in the DOM:

```
if ($(this).is(':last')) {
    alert('last');
}

$(this).remove();
```

Comment: because I want to check if it's last, and it got removed then do something else..

Comment: Well, you can't do the check in that order, sorry. The best you can do is do the check, store the result in a variable, remove the element, then act on the stored result from the `:last` check. You simply cannot remove an element from the DOM and then query it about what it's position *used* to be.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

$(document).on('click', 'li', function () {

```
if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
    alert('last');
}
$(this).remove();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You should use :last-child, also the remove comes after the check not before.

```
$(document).on('click', 'li', function () {

    if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
        alert('last');
    }
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TgfeT/1/)